# How to control cordova-plugin-firebase for cordova?

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification

How to control cordova-plugin-firebase for cordova?

I want to show push notifications if user logged in, otherwise it should not show.

Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add another API for the plugin, to set a boolean (e.g. setLoggedIn()).
You should call it from the JS side with true after login, and false after logout (or login screen is being shown).
On the native side, you should store the value (e.g. on SharedPreferences) and check if the value is true when a new notification arrives.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Check if user is logged in or not
2. You can do this by keeping a field in db and change value to 1 when
   user logs in and 0 when he logs out
3. And than hit api only on those device id's where logged_in status is 1
   may be this helps You